# MySQL test privileges

Tags: mysql, privileges

Let's assume that we have to test some privileges of MySQL database before to execute some program (program daemonizes itself before logging to MySQL, so we can't easily check whether logging will success).

Parsing SHOW GRANTS output is a torture, especially with all these escapes, %, etc.

Is there an easy way to test user privileges (way that connected user can use, not root)?

SELECT is easy to test, but what about such operations like DELETE, INSERT?
Say we have INSERT privilege, but haven't DELETE, so INSERTING smth is not a solution.
Can we INSERT and DELETE "VOID" just to test privileges?

Comment: select * from information_schema.user_privileges WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '%what_ever_your_user_is%'

Answer (score 0):

How about if you select it directly from the information_schema?

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges;
```

Now to parse out the result set, you can either use a client or pipe it to sed to create a csv file, i.e.

```
mysql -uroot -p -e "select * from information_schema.user_privileges" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > grants.csv
```

References:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-privileges-table.html

Comment: Unfortunately after granting INSERT and CREATE privileges for a user, select * from information_schema.user_privileges reports only about USAGE privilege, while SHOW GRANTS shows USAGE, INSERT and CREATE privileges.

Comment: Eventually I have to select from information_schema.schema_privileges, but there is the same problem: if GRANT was made to `squid%`.*, then I will have to parse % and so on, while I want simple solution to chech whether user 'sknaumov'@'localhost' have certain privilege on `squidtest` database.

Answer (score 0):

Privileges can be granted on different level (user level, schema level, table level and even column level). The query below combines those (except column level) and shows you the combined privileges per table (or VIEW).

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, GRANTEE
 , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PRIVILEGE_TYPE ORDER BY PRIVILEGE_TYPE) PRIVILEGE_TYPES
FROM (
 SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, GRANTEE, PRIVILEGE_TYPE
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
  INNER JOIN information_schema.user_privileges USING (TABLE_CATALOG)
  WHERE NOT TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema')
   AND GRANTEE=CONCAT("'", REPLACE(CURRENT_USER(), '@', "'@'"), "'")
 UNION ALL
 SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, GRANTEE, PRIVILEGE_TYPE
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
  INNER JOIN information_schema.schema_privileges USING (TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA)
  WHERE NOT TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema')
   AND GRANTEE=CONCAT("'", REPLACE(CURRENT_USER(), '@', "'@'"), "'")
 UNION ALL
 SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, GRANTEE, PRIVILEGE_TYPE
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
  INNER JOIN information_schema.table_privileges USING (TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)
  WHERE NOT TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema')
   AND GRANTEE=CONCAT("'", REPLACE(CURRENT_USER(), '@', "'@'"), "'")
) u
 GROUP BY TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, GRANTEE
;
```

Note that the way I put quotes around the CURRENT_USER is ugly, but as long as you don't use single quotes or @ signs in your user names, you should be fine. I think.