# Check if you can INSERT into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Suppose a database I am using crashed or had any other error that prevented me from calling `INSERT` on it. After that I want to know whenever the access to the database has returned. What I want to do is check if we have access every `x` seconds (for simplicity - every 1 second). I **do not** want to repeat the instruction - I only need to know if the database is available.

Keep in mind - I don't only need to know if database is up. I also need to know if we are authorized to use it and - overall - if we have rights to call `INSERT` on a specific table.

How can I do this the cleanest (generally speaking - with least amount of code) way with Java? Currently I am using Spring's `JpaRepository`.

Comment: The way we do is we just do a `select` query in a thread

Comment: `select` doesn't tell you if you can `insert` into the table. We would also need to know if we have privileges for `insert`

Comment: @dan1st you mean - try to `insert` every 1 second? And when it succeeded - remove the records we inserted? For bigger queries that could be a performance killer

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8471420/10871900 (jdbc works within jpa too)

Comment: @Rasmond : Could it be the case that your privileges for a table also change at runtime?? If not I suggest you can check that initially and store it globally.

Comment: Also why not just test using select query taht DB is and do your insert as and when require. If you  do no have any access, it will give error and you can catch that exception and send response accordingly

Comment: @RahulAgrawal it absolutely is, as my service is supposed to be up 24h. We need to handle any failure, which also might be messing up with database privileges

Comment: @RahulAgrawal that's a good idea. However in case the privileges have been changed then we are selecting and inserting every second. Then handling an exception and when we finally get our privileges back - we select, insert and then we also have to delete what we inserted. On the other hand - losing privileges is probably rare occasion. In every other situation it probably would be good enough

Answer (score 2):

If you know in advance it is a table level grant you can query the *information_schema*.*table_privileges* table:

```
select * from table_privileges where privilege_type = 'INSERT';
```

If it is a schema level grant use:

```
select * from schema_privileges where privilege_type = 'INSERT';
```

In any case the right thing would be solving the issue at the base. Once you have insert privileges on a table you should not worry about loosing them, unless the revocation is deliberate. Why are grants disappearing? Which is very strange since grants are persistent.

Comment: it doesn't really seem to work. `information_schema.table_privileges` is empty

Comment: then the insert privilege can be found on the other table mentioned in the answer. The schema_privileges should contain a record with the username, privilege type and db name. the table is part of a schema/db on which the user has insert privileges on db.* (all tables of that db)

Comment: the queries in the answer are not elaborate enough, they just show where to look for the insert grant information without effectively trying to insert a record in order to know if you can actually insert.

Comment: `IS_GRANTABLE` is currently `NO` for every single privilege

Comment: I guess IS_GRANTABLE means the "user can grant the privilege to other users". you need to know if the user can insert into a certain table. If schema_privileges has one row with the db name, the user you are using for the connection and the insert privilege, then you can do inserts.

Comment: oh, okay, awesome